# List to Mixed dimension Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have been trying to figure out how to take a list and match the shape of any matrice.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [[3],[[2]],[1,8,2],[[[7,3,2]]],[9]]
```

I want list a to match the dimensions of matrix b. Both a and b have the same number of individual elements. The function requires a and be to have the same number of elements.

```
output = [[1],[[2]],[3,4,5],[[[[6,7,8]],[9]]
```

My attemp at trying to do this.

```
import numpy as np
lst = []
start = 0
def match_matrix(a,b):
    for k, v in enumerate(b):
        shape = np.shape(v)
        lst.append(np.reshape(a[start:start+element_num], newshape= shape) # there problem is here, how would I figure out how many elements in any dimension matrix
         start += element_num

    return lst
```

Comment: Not sure NumPy is the best solution, as you don't have a regular *n*-dimension array, as your array is jagged. Nested lists may be better.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, why you want to use numpy for this. Here is a simple solution to create a list of lists

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> b = [[3],[[2]],[1,8,2],[[[7,3,2]]],[9]]
>>> 
>>> def create_list(l, itr):
...     return [create_list(e, itr) if isinstance(e, list) else next(itr) for e in l]
... 
>>> 
>>> create_list(b, iter(a))
[[1], [[2]], [3, 4, 5], [[[6, 7, 8]]], [9]]
```

Comment: [Don't name lambdas](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).  Just make it a function.  It will make it much more readable anways

Comment: True.. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

This can be done straight-forwardly with recursion. This function assumes that list `b` has the same number of non-list elements than the length of list `a`

```
def match_matrix(a, b):
    it = iter(a)
    def _worker(b):
        lst = []
        for x in b:
            if isinstance(x, list):
                lst.append(_worker(x))
            else:
                lst.append(next(it))
        return lst
    return _worker(b)
```